# Combining Models for different levels of target variable in R

Tags: r, classification, model

I have a classification variable with 7 levels. The crux of the problems comes down to the splitting of levels 1 and 2. Below is the output of a random forest in R.

I want to add a second model which is a model used just for variables 1 and 2 and has a lower mis-classification rate.

I've tried to run the full model and then re-run the second model where the output of the first model was a 1 or 2.

This is not adding any value at present which is not what I expected. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 OOB estimate of  error rate: 10.67%

Confusion matrix:

     1    2    3    4    5    6    7 class.error
1 1731  292    1    0   34    5   97  0.19861111

2  345 1561   56    0  135   48   15  0.27731481

3    0    7 1899   67   21  166    0  0.12083333

4    0    0   35 2101    0   24    0  0.02731481

5    3   21   23    0 2097   16    0  0.02916667

6    0    5  106   42   12 1995    0  0.07638889

7   36    2    0    0    0    0 2122  0.01759259


#train the model on 1 and 2 only

train2 <- train[train$Cover_Type < 3, ]

fit2 <- randomForest(as.factor(Cover_Type) ~., data=train2, importance=TRUE, mtry= 16, ntree=1500)


#train full model on all data

fit1 <- randomForest(as.factor(Cover_Type) ~., data=train, importance=TRUE, mtry= 15, ntree=1500)

# Run a prediction on full data set

Prediction1 <- predict(fit1, test)

submit <- data.frame(Id = test$Id, Cover_Type = Prediction1)

submit$Cover_Type <- as.numeric(submit$Cover_Type)

submit1 <- submit[submit$Cover_Type > 2, ]


# Re -run the prediction where output is a one or a two
test2 <- submit[submit$Cover_Type < 3, ]
test3 <- merge(test,test2,by="Id")

test3$Cover_Type.y <- NULL
test3$Cover_Type.x <- NULL

Prediction2 <- predict(fit2,test3)


submit2 <- data.frame(Id = test3$Id, Cover_Type = Prediction2)

#Combine submit1 and Submit 2
rownames(submit1) <- NULL
submit2$Cover_Type <- as.numeric(submit2$Cover_Type)

total <- rbind(submit2, submit1)

write.csv(total, file = "Test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is perhaps important in the distinction of the two classes is not the fact that they are among other classes that you are not interested in. What is important are the predictors used to build the model. So maybe to reduce the error, you can do some kind of selection of predictors which are most informative.